# split string inside column into new columns

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, split

as you can see in the following picture I have a column with strings inside which differ in length. I would like to split them into 3 new columns and drop the original after doing so.

[image: Postgis]

For example it should look like this in the end:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PLZ (Col1)         Area (Col2)               Name (Col3)
019333             Ostallgäu                 mtb-auerberg-marathon
013389             Gemeinde Schleching       Mountainbikeweg zur Daiseralm
...                ...                       ...
```

Between the first and second part, the slash has no space, but before the last part there is two.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //add 3 new columns(PLZ, Area, Name)
    alter table mytable add column PLZ varchar(100), add column Area 
    varchar(100), add column Name varchar(100);

    update mytable set PLZ = split_part(name,'/','1'), Area = trim(both from 
    split_part(name,'/','2')), Name = trim(both from split_part(name,'/','3'));

    //delete original column (name)
    alter table mytable drop name;
```

Comment: that did the trick but i did not drop the table at the end, i dropped the column

Comment: I did not drop the table at the end, I drop the column

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regexp_split_to_array()`:

```
select
    ar[1] as plz,
    ar[2] as area,
    ar[3] as name
from mytable t
cross join lateral (select regexp_split_to_array(col, E'\\s*/\\s*') ar) x
```

Splitting pattern `'\\s*/\\s*'` describes a slash optionnaly surrounded with spaces.

Comment: thanks! it is just a select not alter table but it helped me understand what i need